# MongoDB query pairs in big collection

Tags: mongodb

I just recently started using MongoDB trying to solve a domain specific problem an got stuck trying to self join a big collection. I have a database with well over 10 million documents, each containing adress elements to an entity (person, organisation, mailbox for an organisation etc.). Note that each depth (for example street) can occur more than once to store some varying information like aliases or depth specific ids. I have no schema restrictions and can change it if it helps solving the question.

The data looks like this:

```
{
  "some_info": "xyz",
  "tags": {
    "HOUSE_NUMBER": [
      {
        "id": "23.45678",
        "value": "18",
        "attributes": ["NU"]
      }
    ],
    "FORENAME": [
      {
        "id": "34.56789",
        "value": "MAX",
        "attributes": ["XQ4", "M"]
      },
      {
        "id": "45.67890",
        "value": "X65732862",
        "attributes": ["XID"]
      }
    ],
    "STREET": [
      {
        "id": "56.789012",
        "value": "RICHMOND STREET",
        "attributes": []
      }
    ],
    "...": []
  }
}
```

I want to query for pairs in the collection, for example "find all pairs of persons with the same forename living in the same street", or "find all pairs of persons and organisations having at least 3 words in common living in the same city". My current query for the first problem looks something like this:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags.STREET"},
    {$unwind: "$tags.FORENAME"},
    {
        $match: {
            "tags.FORENAME.attributes": {$nin: ["XID", "NA"]}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection_name",
            localField: "tags.STREET.id",
            foreignField: "tags.STREET.id",
            as: "joined"
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$joined"},
    {$unwind: "$joined.tags.FORENAME"},
    {
        $match: {$expr: {$ne: ["$tags.FORENAME.id", "$joined.tags.FORENAME.id"]}}
    },
    {
        $match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$tags.FORENAME.value", "$joined.tags.FORENAME.value"]}}
    }
], {
    allowDiskUse: true
})
```

I created indices on tags.STREET.id, tags.FORENAME.id, tags.FORENAME.attributes and tags.FORENAME.value.

The problem with this is the execution time. I just can't get to an acceptable level, the above mentioned query takes 3.5 minutes for 500 results on my machine. For comparison, my PostgreSQL database (with specifically created views and indices for the problem) only takes a few seconds.

How can I speed up this kind of queries? Is MongoDB even suitable for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is a *VERY* expensive stage for Mongo to execute, and in this specific case, completely unneeded. not to mention you are doing it on the entire collection.

I would re-write this pipeline like so, utilizing [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) instead of `$lookup`:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: "$tags.STREET"
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$tags.FORENAME"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "tags.FORENAME.attributes": {$nin: ["XID", "NA"]}
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {foreName: "$tags.FORENAME.value", streetId: "tags.STREET.id"},
                docs: {$addToSet: "$$ROOT"}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "docs.1": {$exists: true}
            }
        },
        //Add whichever other structure changes you need.
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true
});
```

Now this is still a somewhat expensive pipeline as we have to `$unwind` and `$group` the entire collection, but it will be much much faster than the current version.

I do not know how your data / product works, so it's hard to give a better "solution" to how the schema/collection architecture should be built.

With that said an easy improvement I see right off the bat is changing the `street` and `forename` structure from an array to an object. (unless you can have multiple streets and forename's and then does a relational database work well for you?) this will make the first 3 stages of the current pipeline redundant and will boost performance.

---

EDIT:
Negating condition is not possible while grouping but we can work around it by adding an additional `$group` stage.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: "$tags.STREET"
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$tags.FORENAME"
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$tags.HOUSE_NUMBER"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "tags.FORENAME.attributes": {$nin: ["XID", "NA"]}
            }
        },
        {
            $group:{
                "_id": {foreName: "$tags.FORENAME.value", streetId: "tags.STREET.id", houseName: "tags.HOUSE_NUMBER.id"},
                docs: {$addToSet: "$$ROOT"}
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {foreName: "$tags.FORENAME.value", streetId: "tags.STREET.id"},
                docs: {$addToSet: "$docs"}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "docs.1": {$exists: true}
            }
        },
        //Add whichever other structure changes you need.
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very interesting. I dind't know it's possible to group by multiple keys. This brings the execution time down to a few minutes for 10k+ results, which is definitely in the acceptable range. It's not possible to "negate" a condition tho, or is it? For example, I need to pair only those persons living in a differeny house number.

Comment: It's not possible to `$group` with a negation condition. i added and edit section to my answer with a sample workaround on how to deal with it.

Comment: I unfortunately run into memory restrictions with this workaround. I already modified your query to only add the _id to the docs array in the first group stage to circumvent the 100mb memory limit. With the second group stage in place I somehow run into the 16mb document size limit (BSONObj size: 55293437 (0x34BB5FD) is invalid).
Do you think MongoDB is even suitable for this kind of problem? The queries run well in PostgreSQL once developed, but compares to MongoDB it's a pain to work with and visualize the data, not to mention the time it takes to develop an appropriate query.

Comment: The current structure do not make Mongo look good as it does not utilize Mongo's strengths. It's hard to say what it could be changed into as i don't know how your data is collected and used for. If you already have an SQL architecture setup that you're happy with and serves you well then just go for it.

Comment: I'd like to give more data, but obviously it's pretty sensitive. The document in the initial post contains all relevant fields and is only missing some additional tags tho. I'm still experimenting with different technologies to find the best setup, SQL is not yet the winner :)
Thanks again for your help, I might could just pre filter the data with your first query and apply more complex contitions in the application itself; as long as I don't have to iterate through millions of documents the execution time should still be acceptable.